# If column 1 does not contain any substrings from list, combine with a cleaned column 2 into a new column

Tags: python, string, append, substring, concatenation

I have a tough situation here where I need to perform multiple operations to get a new column. I have a list of substrings. If 'company' column does not contain any of the substrings from list, I have to combine 'compnay' with 'city' (without numbers) into a 'new' column. In contrast, 'new' will return 'company' column if there is match of substring.

substring list

```
list=['co','co.','ltd','ltd.','limited','inc','inc.']
```

Current dataframe

```
City              Company
10001 New York    Nike ltd
Paris             Louis Vuitton
689 Tokyo         Nissan inc.
Milan             Ferrari co
999 Hong Kong     Li&Fung 
Vancouver         Lululemon
Seoul             Samsung limited
```

Desired output

```
City              Company               New
10001 New York    Nike Ltd              Nike Ltd
2345 Paris        Louis Vuitton         Louis Vuitton, Paris
689 Tokyo         Nissan inc.           Nissan inc.
Milan             Ferrari co            Ferrari co
999 Hong Kong     Li&Fung               Li&Fung, Hong Kong
Vancouver         Lululemon             Lululemon, Vancouver
Seoul             Samsung limited       Samsung Limited
```

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas.Series.where`, `str.contains` and `extract`:

```
l=['co','co.','ltd','ltd.','limited','inc','inc.']
s = df["Company"]
city = df["City"].str.extract("(\D+)",expand=False).str.strip()
df["new"] = s.where(s.str.contains("|".join(l)), 
                    lambda x:x+", "+city)
print(df)
```

print(df)

Output:

```
             City          Company                   new
0  10001 New York         Nike ltd              Nike ltd
1           Paris    Louis Vuitton  Louis Vuitton, Paris
2       689 Tokyo      Nissan inc.           Nissan inc.
3           Milan       Ferrari co            Ferrari co
4   999 Hong Kong          Li&Fung   Li&Fung,  Hong Kong
5       Vancouver        Lululemon  Lululemon, Vancouver
6           Seoul  Samsung limited       Samsung limited
```